# Números aleatórios são sempre os mesmos

Tags: c++, random

Por que este código está exibindo sempre os mesmos resultados de números aleatórios de um dado?

```
// Figura 6.9: fig06_09.cpp
// Lança um dado de seis lados 6.000.000 de vezes.
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

#include <cstdlib> // contém o protótipo de função para rand
using std::rand;

int main()
{
    int frequency1 = 0; // contagem de 1s lançado
    int frequency2 = 0; // contagem de 2s lançado
    int frequency3 = 0; // contagem de 3s lançado
    int frequency4 = 0; // contagem de 4s lançado
    int frequency5 = 0; // contagem de 5s lançado
    int frequency6 = 0; // contagem de 6s lançado

    int face; // armazena o valor lançado mais recente

    // resume os resultados de 6,000,000 lançamentos de um dado
    for(int roll = 1; roll <= 6000000; roll++ )
    {
        face = 1 + rand() % 6;

        // determina valor de lançamento de 1 a 6 e incrementa o contador apropriado
        switch(face)
        {
            case 1:
                ++frequency1;
                break;
            case 2:
                ++frequency2;
                break;
            case 3:
                ++frequency3;
                break;
            case 4:
                ++frequency4;
                break;
            case 5:
                ++frequency5;
                break;
            case 6:
                ++frequency6;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Program should never get here!";
        } // fim do switch
    } // fim do for

    cout << "Face" << setw(13) << "Frequency" << endl;
    cout << "   1" << setw(13) << frequency1
        << "\n  2" << setw(13) << frequency2
        << "\n  3" << setw(13) << frequency3
        << "\n  4" << setw(13) << frequency4
        << "\n  5" << setw(13) << frequency5
        << "\n  6" << setw(13) << frequency6 << endl;
    return 0; // indica terminação bem-sucedida
}  // fim de main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa inicializar a semente dos números randômicos. Geralmente se faz isso pelo relógio do computador, que atende bem situações simples. Se precisar de uma melhor distribuição é melhor usar o gerador randômico do próprio C++ e não do C, ele é muito melhor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> // contém o protótipo de função para rand
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int frequency1 = 0; // contagem de 1s lançado
    int frequency2 = 0; // contagem de 2s lançado
    int frequency3 = 0; // contagem de 3s lançado
    int frequency4 = 0; // contagem de 4s lançado
    int frequency5 = 0; // contagem de 5s lançado
    int frequency6 = 0; // contagem de 6s lançado
    int face; // armazena o valor lançado mais recente
    for (int roll = 1; roll <= 6000000; roll++) {
        face = 1 + rand() % 6;
        switch (face) {
            case 1:
                ++frequency1;
                break;
            case 2:
                ++frequency2;
                break;
            case 3:
                ++frequency3;
                break;
            case 4:
                ++frequency4;
                break;
            case 5:
                ++frequency5;
                break;
            case 6:
                ++frequency6;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Program should never get here!";
        } // fim do switch
    } // fim do for
    cout << "Face" << setw(13) << "Frequency" << endl;
    cout << "  1" << setw(13) << frequency1
        << "\n  2" << setw(13) << frequency2
        << "\n  3" << setw(13) << frequency3
        << "\n  4" << setw(13) << frequency4
        << "\n  5" << setw(13) << frequency5
        << "\n  6" << setw(13) << frequency6 << endl;
}  // fim de main
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8kJwQh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/puycnuxk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Seeding.cpp).

Answer (score 5):

A função `rand` gera números que são pseudo-randômicos. Ou seja, para que se tenha a sensação de algo mais aleatório, é necessário modificar a semente dos números. Isso é realizado pela função [srand()](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand). No início da função `main` vc pode colocar algo do tipo:

```
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A sequencia de números aleatórios gerados, de fato, sempre serão os mesmos para uma mesma semente, essa é uma característica fundamental de um [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

Para se obter sequências diferentes é necessário que a [semente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) utilizada seja "aleatória".

Essa semente aleatória pode ser obtida a partir do relógio interno do computador, fazendo com que a semente seja diferente a cada "momento".

Seguem dois exemplos (testados) baseados no programa original da sua pergunta.

Em `C++98`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define QTD_LADOS        (6)
#define QTD_LANCES_MAX   (6000000)

int main()
{
    int p[ QTD_LADOS ] = {};

    std::srand( std::time(NULL) );

    for( int i = 0; i < QTD_LANCES_MAX; i++ )
        p[ std::rand() % 6 ]++;

    for( int i = 0; i < QTD_LADOS; i++ )
        std::cout << i+1 << ". " << p[i] << " [" << ( ( p[i] * 100.0 ) / QTD_LANCES_MAX ) << "%]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Em `C++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

#define QTD_LADOS        (6)
#define QTD_LANCES_MAX   (6000000)

int main()
{
    int p[ QTD_LADOS ] = {};

    unsigned int seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

    std::default_random_engine gen( seed );
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist( 1, 6 );

    for( int i = 0; i < QTD_LANCES_MAX; i++ )
        p[ dist(gen) - 1 ]++;

    for( int i = 0; i < QTD_LADOS; i++ )
        std::cout << i+1 << ". " << p[i] << " [" << ( ( p[i] * 100.0 ) / QTD_LANCES_MAX ) << "%]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Possível saída:

```
$ ./rand
1. 999484 [16.6581%]
2. 998792 [16.6465%]
3. 1000396 [16.6733%]
4. 1001144 [16.6857%]
5. 1000860 [16.681%]
6. 999324 [16.6554%]
```